# Долгий MySQL запрос

Tags: оптимизация, mysql

Данный запрос грузит примерно 7-15 секунд.

- **users** - 10 000 записей
- **tasks_done** - 300 000 записей

Индексы стоят.

EXPLAIN

[image: explain]

> ```
> SELECT `users`.`uid`, `users`.`uavatar`  
> COUNT(`tasks_done`.`tdid`) as `count_tasks_done` 
> FROM `tasks_done`    
> INNER JOIN `users` ON (`tasks_done`.`tduid` = `users`.`uid`)   
> WHERE `tasks_done`.`tdtype` = 'done' AND `users`.`uban_type` = 0 AND `users`.`udel` = 0 AND `users`.`top` = 0    
> GROUP BY `tasks_done`.`tduid`     
> ORDER BY `count_tasks_done` DESC  
> LIMIT 100
> ```

Таблица **users**:

> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
> `uid` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
> `ulogin` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
> `upassword` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
> `uemail` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
> `temp_password` varchar(32) NOT NULL, 
> `uemail_activated` tinyint(1) NOT
> NULL,   `uemail_helper` tinyint(1) NOT
> NULL,   `uvk_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
> `uname` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
> `ulast_name` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
> `uip_address` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
> `ureg_time` int(10) NOT NULL,
> `ulast_time` int(10) NOT NULL,
> `ugender` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
> `ugroup` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
> `upoints` int(10) NOT NULL,
> `uban_type` int(1) NOT NULL,
> `uban_time` int(10) NOT NULL,
> `uban_text` text NOT NULL,   `uhash`
> varchar(100) NOT NULL,
> `blacklist_notif` int(3) NOT NULL,
> `uavatar` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
> `uagent_id` int(6) NOT NULL,
> `uagent_avatar` tinyint(2) NOT NULL,
> `uagent_rate_plus` int(10) NOT NULL,
> `uagent_rate_minus` int(10) NOT NULL, 
> `udel` int(10) NOT NULL,   `city`
> int(4) NOT NULL,   `ubrowser`
> varchar(50) NOT NULL,   `ubyear`
> smallint(4) NOT NULL,   `complaints`
> int(10) NOT NULL,   `account`
> tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
> `vk_time_update` int(10) NOT NULL,
> `top` smallint(1) NOT NULL,   PRIMARY
> KEY (`uid`),   UNIQUE KEY `ulogin`
> (`ulogin`),   UNIQUE KEY `uemail`
> (`uemail`),   KEY `ugroup` (`ugroup`),
> KEY `ulast_time` (`ulast_time`),   KEY
> `udel` (`udel`),   KEY `uvk_id`
> (`uvk_id`),   KEY `uemail_activated`
> (`uemail_activated`),   KEY
> `uban_type` (`uban_type`),   KEY
> `ureg_time` (`ureg_time`),   KEY
> `vk_time_update` (`vk_time_update`),
> KEY `top` (`top`) ) ENGINE=InnoDB 
> DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
> AUTO_INCREMENT=9352 ;

Таблица **tasks_done**:

> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
> `tasks_done` (   `tdid` bigint(30) NOT
> NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,   `tduid` int(10)
> NOT NULL,   `tdvk_id` int(10) NOT
> NULL,   `tdtid` int(10) NOT NULL,
> `tdurl` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET
> cp1251 NOT NULL,   `tdtype`
> varchar(30) CHARACTER SET cp1251 NOT
> NULL,   `tdtime` int(10) NOT NULL,
> `tdsection` tinyint(2) NOT NULL,
> `tdread` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
> `unique_key` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
> PRIMARY KEY (`tdid`),   UNIQUE KEY
> `unique_key` (`unique_key`),   KEY
> `tduid` (`tduid`),   KEY `tdtid`
> (`tdtid`),   KEY `tdurl` (`tdurl`),
> KEY `tdtype` (`tdtype`),   KEY
> `tdsection` (`tdsection`),   KEY
> `tdread` (`tdread`),   KEY `tdtime`
> (`tdtime`) ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT
> CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=275732 ;

Comment: а где `EXPLAIN` запроса?

Comment: @ua6xh, вот, заскринил http://clip2net.com/clip/m40641/1386600679-clip-8kb.png

Comment: @ModaL - есть [мнение][1] что count(field) тормозит ваш запрос, сделайте count(*)

[1]: http://voituk.kiev.ua/2006/07/27/mysql-right-count-statement/

Comment: @ua6xh, не помогло :(

Comment: @ModaL - Начал разбирать таблицу tasks_done - зачем столько ключей? избыточные индексы тоже плохо. Щас подумаемс...

Comment: @ua6xh, как бы не только в одном месте выборка из tasks_done.. Ещё на другой странице есть выборка по индексным ключам, но она быстрая, так как видимо там нет count и join'а.

Comment: @ModaL - Вы знаете про составные индексы на несколько полей?
UPD: 
1. комменты закончились, пиши в [vk][1]
2. стало чуть [веселее][2], но надо пробовать на бекапе базы


[1]: http://vk.com/ua6xh
[2]: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dcbfc/1

Comment: Так а как вообще этот запрос может работать быстро, если надо взять все 300000 задач, разбить их по пользователям, сгруппировать и отсортировать? Хотя, "всего" 300000. Допустим, выполнение за одну секунду тоже устроит?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

имхо, колонки `ban_type` и `udel` можно было бы объединить. удаленный или забаненный в любом случае неактивный, просто еще один тип бана - удален.
что такое колонка `top` сложно догадаться, но такое ощущение, что индексы по всем этим трем колонкам не приносят пользы - отсечение идет малого от большого, в итоге остается слишком большой процент юзеров, смысла в применении таких индексов нет, чтоб потом все равно делать по ним почти полный скан.
`tdtype` - строковая колонка, индекс большой по ней.

такое количество индексов приводит к тому, что оптимизатор выбирает индексы как хочет. Надо уже пользоваться [хинтами](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/index-hints.html).

для данного запроса, я бы попробовал индекс по `(tduid,tdtype)`, согласен с [@Andrew Frolov](/users/1514/andrew-frolov), притом оставил бы только этот индекс.
т.к. юзеры будут перебираться все равно все. в любом случае нужно будет обойти всех чтоб получить по ним количество выполненных заданий и отсортировать по этому количеству, а потом взять первых 100.

ЗЫ filesort по юзерам это конечно вилы.

Comment: Хинты это final argument, когда статистика не помогает. Статистику надо собирать, а не хинтовать всё подряд.

Comment: @Andrew Frolov, я на 99% уверен, что использование одного индекса из этих трех будет быстрее чем использование объединения, а в данном случае эти индексы вообще лишние, имхо. это следует из прикладного смысла этих полей. по поводу статистики я согласен, что она нужна, хинты - это борьба с тучей индексов, а не final argument.

Answer (score 1):

Таблицы, конечно, ужасные. Названия колонок, апострофы, куча непонятных ключей.. Но сейчас не об этом :)

Я бы для начала проверил настройки mysql. Не дефалтовые, надеюсь? 
Потом сделал бы такой индекс.

```
create index tasks_done_idx on tasks_done(tduid,tdtype)
```

Потом, наверное, стоит попробовать сделать ещё один индекс на users, чтобы не пришлось 3 индекса мерджить.

```
create index user_idx on user(top,udel, ban_type)
```

Потом собрал бы статистику.

```
ANALYZE TABLE tasks_done;
ANALYZE TABLE users;
```